# PowerMock not using mocked "new" object

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, powermockito

I have a Spring Boot project and trying to use PowerMockito to mock an object that is created inside the method.

I have some code that is declaring a new Object that is extending an Abstract class:

```
@Service
public class InstanceService {

   public Instance createJenkinsInstance(RequestSpecification request){
        ParentInstance instance = new DefaultInstance(kubernetesUtil);
        instance.provisionForNewInstance(request);
   ...
   }
}
```

The DefaultInstance class:

```
public class DefaultInstance extends ParentInstance {
  public DefaultInstance(KubernetesUtil kubernetesUtil) {
    super(kubernetesUtil);
  }

  public DefaultInstance(KubernetesUtil kubernetesUtil, Environment env) {
    super(kubernetesUtil, env);
  }
```

The ParentInstance class:

```
@Data
public abstract class ParentInstance {
   public ParentInstance(KubernetesUtil kubernetesUtil) {
    this.kubernetesUtil = kubernetesUtil;
    /*some code*/
  }

  public ParentInstance(KubernetesUtil kubernetesUtil, Environment env) {
    this.kubernetesUtil = kubernetesUtil;
    this.env = env;
    /*some code*/
  }
  /* Class contains more functions */
```

My test looks like the following:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({InstanceService.class})
public class InstanceServicePowerMockTest {
    @Test
    public void testCreateInstance() throws Exception {
      logger.info("in testCreateInstance2 mock");
      DefaultInstance instanceMock = PowerMockito.mock(DefaultInstance.class);
      PowerMockito.whenNew(DefaultInstance.class)
          .withArguments(any())
          .thenReturn(instanceMock);
      
   
      PowerMockito.when(instanceMock.provisionForNewInstance(any())).thenReturn(true);

      RequestSpecification requestSpecification = new RequestSpecification();
      requestSpecification.setName("test");

      InstanceService instanceService = new InstanceService();
      instanceService.createJenkinsInstance(requestSpecification);

      verifyNew(DefaultInstance.class).withArguments(any());
    }
}
```

My test isn't working, I notice that the DefaultInstance is being created in the test rather than using the mocked object I have created. I have searched around online for a while, and tried different things I found others doing. I'm wondering if the issue is I'm trying to mock an object that extends an Abstract class. How can I fix this?

Btw, the InstanceService class autowires some DAO classes to save objects to the Database. Does powermock support this?

Comment: Why use powermock(ito). Just use mockito to mock the  service and when the `createJenkinsInstance` return the mocked instance. I consider things like PowerMock to be the wrong thing for testing and if you cannot do it (easily) with regular Mockito you have something wrong in your design.